# How to catch NestJS exceptions thrown in `forFeature` or `forRoot`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, nestjs-config

I setuped configuration validation as described in documentation of NestJS: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#schema-validation

Validation works as expected, but when my `.env` file is not valid, I am getting plain error, for example:

> Error: Config validation error: "FOO_BAR" is required
>       at Function.forRoot (`<PATH>\@nestjs\config\dist\config.module.js:44:27`)

This error is not thrown by Nest so approach with `globalFilter` what can catch every Nest error not work:
https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/exception-filters#exception-filters

How to catch this error to be able to format it?

EDIT: This is more general question: How to catch errors thrown inside `forRoot, forFeature` in NestJS?

Comment: How would you like to format the error? Are you trying to send it somewhere?

Comment: No. I am just trying to catch it and do nice formatting...But I am not able to catch error what is thrown in `forRoot` of module... It seems like poor design.

Comment: You could always try wrapping the `NestFactory.create` in a `try/catch` and catch all startup errors. Not really sure what you'd be doing with formatting for the error, but I'd say essentially if an error is thrown on bootstrap you wouldn't want the server to start in the first place

Comment: Not working. I already tried this. Also I do not want to start server, I just want nicer error to let user know about whats wrong and not annoy him with long stacks.